# Formatting Equation Numbers

Tags: equations, numbering, bold, text-decorations

I need the numbers of equations and brackets around to be in bold. 
Doing like this

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\theequation}{\bf}{}{}
```

only the number is produced in bold, how to bold brackets?

And second question. I want my references to equations also to be with bolded brackets automatically, how to do this?

Comment: Are you using the `amsmath` package?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `\tagform@#1` from `amsmath.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries[\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a = b.
\end{equation}
As we see from equation~\eqref{eq:test}... 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even used \eqref{} for this, thought that it should be done like this [\ref{}].

Comment: @Pavasaris you're welcome! The advantage of using `\eqref` over `\ref` is that the former automatically supplies the declared format around the equation number.

Answer (score 6):

The »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« package can do this job for you.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \newtagform{bbrackets}[\textbf]{\textbf{[}}{\textbf{]}}
  \usetagform{bbrackets}
  \begin{equation}
    a^2+b^2=c^2
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```