# Changing align environment tag styles and colors

Tags: math-mode, equations, color, amsmath

I'm using `amsmath` and `amsfonts` to typeset my homework, and since it will be read on a screen, I would like to make `\tag{comments inside equations}` differently colored, and optimally downsize them by a few points.

While I could put `\color` and font instructions in every `\tag` instance, I've got them scattered all over the place and would like a unified way to change it globally. I have figured out how to use the `sectsty` package to color all section fonts to make them stand out on-screen slightly, is there a similar method for `amsmath`'s align environment and tags?

Forgive my extreme TeX ignorance. Also forgive my math ignorance... here's some sample stuff:

```
\begin{align*}
A &= B
\\ &=
\frac{B}{\text{sometimes the equation gets really long so the tag goes on the next line}}
\tag{Here is where I say something stupid}
\\ &=
\frac{1}{0} = \infty
\tag{Tags often include math, like $\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}$}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: This question is very similar to [Formatting equation numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57080/5764). The idea would be to redefine `\tagform@` and insert something like `\color{red}`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: You really should not be using `\tag` for comments. That is not considered proper style on paper. It is fine in pen and paper or on a blackboard but should be avoided in typeset form.

Comment: @daleif: In this case, what would you recommend for annotating long chains of aligned equations then?

Comment: @Werner: I'm not enough of a wizard to understand the redefine solution, but I think the other post there about [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) is going to lead to an easy solution - thanks!

Comment: @daleif -- just a silly, wild idea.  what about something like `\intertext` or `\shortintertext`, but flush right, maybe slightly smaller type, and/or highlighted in some other way, such as colored?  for longer comment text, would want to have a line length narrower than the full page width and allow for multiple lines.  (no suggestions on how to actually do it though.)

Comment: i voted against closing this because it's a different question.  the proposed duplicate will work reliably only if the "tag" is very short.  the text requested by this question is open-ended; it can conceivably be long enough to require more than one line.  so it really isn't a tag at all, and requires a different approach.  the "margin comments" in thomas' calculus text are mentioned as a possibility.  (is thomas still being used?  i had that textbook as a freshman in antediluvian times.)

Comment: I would use standard \interest and \shortintertext to explain what needs to be explained. I would not right align it as Barbara mention. Plus if one need that many explanations I would group them or consider rephrasing.

Comment: Perhaps I should have phrased my question differently, as I am still learning about typography and options within LaTeX. I will try out \intertext, \interest, and \shortintertext, thanks! And yes, it is true, Thomas is still the text... up to 12th edition now.

Comment: You might see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27283/15925 for putting side comments on calculations

Comment: Fantastic, @AndrewSwann, the non-accepted solution you edited showing align mode's `&&\text{(long comment)}` looks like exactly what I was looking for and is the actual answer. That plus `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` should give me all I want for adding ridiculous commentary to my homework. Then I'll just figure out how to rewrite them to add color. This question should probably be closed or cancelled or whatever; I now agree that `\tag` is not the right way to do this.

Comment: Very good.  I am voting to close this as duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27283/15925

Answer (score 2):

Despite this not being "proper style", Werner's comment led me to `mathtools`, which lets you do:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{blue}[\color{blue}]{(}{)}
\usetagform{blue}
```

Works well enough, less confusing to a newbie like me than redefining tagform:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{blue}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
```

which also works.

(I'm actually just attempting to ape the little blue right-margin comments in the [Thomas' Calculus](http://wps.aw.com/aw_thomas_calculus_series/) text.)