# Removing the brackets around equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I am using the `equation` environment with the `amsmath` package.
I would like to remove the brackets on each side of the equation numbering.

I would like to have my equation labelled as  1,   2,  3 ... instead of (1),  (2),   (3).

Is there an appropriate command for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Changing align environment tag styles and colors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134300/5764)

Answer (score 16):

If you are using `amsmath`, just redefine `\tagform@` in this way

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

As egreg notices, you might want `\eqref` to keep the parenthesis when printing the reference. In this case, replace the above code with

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldtagform@\tagform@
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\oldtagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\oldtagform@\tagform@
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\oldtagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
  x=y
\end{equation}
A reference to equation \eqref{myeq}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note that this will remove the parentheses also with `\eqref`, which may be wanted or not.

Comment: @egreg I presume that `\eqref` should have the same behavior as the tag. Anyway, I've added how to circumvent this.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the parentheses to begin with. It was just a remark.

Comment: @JulienBernard You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: I would like to do the opposite: remove the parentheses only when printing the reference, but not when labeling equations.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor \theequation}}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor \theequation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's tagged `amsmath`...