# Omit round brackets around equation numbers with cleveref

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, cleveref, brackets

By default equation numbers produced with the `equation` environment are put in round brackets. I want to get rid of these on the equation line as well as when referencing. karlkoeller gave a solution for this on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228448/removing-the-brackets-around-equation-numbering) post (this solution requires `amsmath`).

But this fails when citing with `\cref` from the `cleveref` package while `\autoref` and the default `\ref` work as expected. See the MWE below.

How can this issue be solved? Or is it wiser to just switch to `\autoref`?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228448/removing-the-brackets-around-equation-numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
%=====================================================
\begin{document}
foo
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}
Something is shown in \cref{eq:foo}. Also in \autoref{eq:foo}. And in equation \ref{eq:foo}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [formatting - Is it possible to remove parenthesis from single cref references? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263523/is-it-possible-to-remove-parenthesis-from-single-cref-references) for alternative solutions that allow toggling

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `\creflabelformat` as follows

```
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}
```

helps.

[image: creflabelformat]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228448/removing-the-brackets-around-equation-numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother

\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}

\begin{document}
foo
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}
Something is shown in \cref{eq:foo}. Also in \autoref{eq:foo}. And in equation \ref{eq:foo}.
\end{document}
```

Thanks to Mico for mentioning in the comments that you should consider using `\textup{}` to ensure an upright font for the references.

Comment: This removes the brackets as wanted, but it also removes the hyperlink. Is there a way to keep the link?

Comment: Executing `\creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}` fails to adhere to an important typographic convention, *viz.*, that equation numbers should *always* be typeset in upright ("roman") mode even if the surrounding text material is typeset in italics. Better to execute `\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}`.

Comment: Note, for anyone else coming across this in 2021, the `creflabelformat` solution now retains links, so should be considered preferable, in my view.