# Reference subequations without parentheses with cleveref

Tags: amsmath, cleveref

Is there a possibility to reference subequations with `cleveref` without parentheses?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%\crefformat{subequations}{eq.~#2#1#3}% doesn't work as intended

\begin{document}
    
Equation:

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        a &= b \label{eq:sub1}\\
        c &= d. \label{eq:sub2}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

References:

\ref{eq:sub1} without parentheses!

\cref{eq:sub1} with parentheses

\end{document}
```

Apparently the "regular" `\ref`command references the subequation without the parentheses. Using the commented out line with `\crefformat` didn't change anything at all unfortunately.

The notated counter (1a) and (1b) behind each subequation should not be affected by the required changes to the style of references.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373064/250119. Change `equation` to `subequations` though

Comment: @user202729 if you don't mind: would you like to submit your comment as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: As it is the same answer the other user gave me, yes this did solve my question.