# Text colour in empheq for multiline AMS environments

Tags: color, amsmath, empheq, colorbox

I use the `empheq` package along with the `xcolor` package to display equations in coloured boxes. I also wish to change the text colour of the equation. In single-line environments, such as `equation`, this works perfectly. With multi-line AMS environments, however, the text colour is only applied to the first line, then the equation goes on with the default colour from the second line.

The MWE goes as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand{\HEG}[1]{\begin{empheq}[box = \colorbox{Thistle4}]{gather}{\color{Snow1}#1}\end{empheq}}
\begin{document}
        \HEG{\mathcal{T}\left(a_1\left\{x_{1k}\right\} + a_2\left\{x_{2k}\right\}\right) =\\\nonumber
        = a_1 \mathcal{T}\left(\left\{x_{1k}\right\}\right) + a_2 \mathcal{T}\left(\left\{x_{2k}\right\}\right)}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following output:
[image]

Manually inserting colour definition at the beginning of the new line will work, ie:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand{\HEG}[1]{\begin{empheq}[box = \colorbox{Thistle4}]{gather}{\color{Snow1}#1}\end{empheq}}
\begin{document}
        \HEG{\mathcal{T}\left(a_1\left\{x_{1k}\right\} + a_2\left\{x_{2k}\right\}\right) =\\\nonumber
        \color{Snow1}= a_1 \mathcal{T}\left(\left\{x_{1k}\right\}\right) + a_2 \mathcal{T}\left(\left\{x_{2k}\right\}\right)}
\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

Is there a way to configure `empheq` to keep the text colour across multiple lines without manual insertions of the colour definition? Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Change color before the environment (observe the braces to group it): `\newcommand{\HEG}[1]{{\color{Snow1}\begin{empheq}[box = \colorbox{Thistle4}]{gather}{#1}\end{empheq}}}`

Comment: @Sigur: thank you, that works perfectly.

Comment: @Sigur, please extend your comment to an answer.

Comment: Unrelated: no need to load `amsmath` before `empheq`.

Comment: @Sigur, you are welcome! (+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(works for non numbered only)**

You can apply the color to the whole environment simply using `\color{}` before it. But, make sure that the color changes apply only to the environment, so **embrace** everything with braces, that is,

```
{\color{<color>}...}
```

[image]

*Off topic:* I would not use those `\left \right`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand{\HEG}[1]{%
  {\color{Snow1}%
    \begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{Thistle4}]{gather}{#1}\end{empheq}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
Text in normal color.
\HEG{
  \mathcal{T} (a_1 \{x_{1k}\} + a_2 \{x_{2k}\}) = \\ 
  a_1 \mathcal{T}(\{x_{1k}\}) + a_2 \mathcal{T}(\{x_{2k}\})
}
Text in normal color.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow this is killing the equation numbering...

Comment: @campa, it is not killing, but changing its color also.... lol

Comment: Ah, of course... silly me `:-P`

Comment: For me, numbering colour is all right as I use the suggestion at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134300/changing-align-environment-tag-styles-and-colors
```\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\footnotesize\fontspec{CMU Serif}\color{Grey}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 6):

A small variation of Sigur's answer: I define an *environment* instead of a macro (my idiosyncrasy: I find it better to read) and declare a new tag form which guarantees that the equation number is still printed in black.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}

% provided by mathtools, which is loaded by empheq
\newtagform{black}{\textcolor{black}\bgroup(}{)\egroup}

\newenvironment{important}[1][gather] % optional parameter defaults to gather
{%
 \usetagform{black}%
 \color{Snow1}%
 \setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{#1}%
 \setkeys{EmphEqOpt}{box=\colorbox{Thistle4}}%
 \EmphEqMainEnv
}{\endEmphEqMainEnv}


\begin{document}

See
\begin{important}
\mathcal{T}(a_1\{x_{1k}\} + a_2\{x_{2k}\}) = \nonumber \\
 = a_1 \mathcal{T} (\{x_{1k}\}) + a_2 \mathcal{T}(\{x_{2k}\})
\end{important}
or similarly
\begin{important}[align]
\mathcal{T}(a_1\{x_{1k}\} + a_2\{x_{2k}\}) &= \\ \nonumber
 &= a_1 \mathcal{T} (\{x_{1k}\}) + a_2 \mathcal{T}(\{x_{2k}\})
\end{important}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice!!