# Equation numbering style

Tags: equations, formatting, numbering, tikz-styles

How to number in line equations and displaymode equations with filled circles? That is I need the equation number in white color and instead of braces it should have black filled circle around the number. Also eqref has to use the same style.

Comment: How should equation numbers greater than 9 be formatted: in a larger circle, or in some kind of ovoid-like shape? Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57083/19372), use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-4pt]
  \node[circle,fill=black,text=white] at (0,0) {\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a = b.
\end{equation}
As we see from equation~\eqref{eq:test}... 

\end{document}
```

To get:

[image]

As @Mico notes, if you have more than 9 numbered equations, the size of the node will change. You can keep the nodes sizes all the same by adding `minimum size=20pt` or similar to the `\node` options in the header.